Create TS type from import.meta.glob data
I'm pulling in a bunch of JSON files that each has an id inside of its data.
export type CourseInfo = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  fullName: string;
  sku: string | null;
  par: string;
  buyCourseDescription: string | null;
  price: string;
  onSaleFrom: string | null;
  isFirm: boolean;
  holes: CourseHoleInfo[];
  courseImage: string;
  courseBuyImage: string;
  courseLogo: string | null;
  courseLogoHorizontal: string | null;
  status: CourseAvailability;
  overrideData: object;
};

const courseModules = import.meta.glob('./*.json', {
  eager: true,
});
const COURSES: CourseInfo[] = [];

Object.keys(courseModules).forEach(key => {
  COURSES.push(courseModules[key].default);
});

const courseIds = COURSES.map(({id}) => id);

The courseIds are now something like ['a', 'b', 'c', ...etc] and I'd like to create a type that only allows a union of these values (i.e. type CourseId = 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | ...etc). Is this possible?

Can you include the typing for CourseInfo?

@AngYC Edited to add it.

Updated on 4/22/2024
I misunderstood that you wanted. The below will go OK? I've also asked this to Copilot.
const courseId = ['a', 'b', 'c'] as const;
type CourseIds = typeof courseId[number]; 
const something: CourseIds = 'a';


Is this that you expected?
type CourseIds = keyof CourseInfo;
const something: CourseIds = 'id';


Not quite. The id would be one of the values specified, like ‘a’ or ‘b’ etc and if I passed something else like ‘foo’ it would error.

Unfortunately because the modules are populated dynamically at run time, that won't work.

@reintroducing When runtime, TypeScript has nothing to do.

Yeah, that's kind of what I figured, but just wanted to know if there was something I was missing that could make this happen. :\
